# Is it possible to list all RemoteIO audio units currently in the application?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I'd like to add an output render callback via `AudioUnitAddRenderNotify` onto the currently active RemoteIO unit that's outputting audio to the speakers. I don't have access to the actual RemoteIO instance variable, but I'd like to get a list audio units in the app and find the RemoteIO unit that way. Is this even possible?

Comment: Interesting question -- how is it that you don't have access to the instance variable?  Is it being created in a static library or something?

Comment: Curious to know of a solution also. In my particular case, it is being handled by Unity3d's underlying fmod implementation, which I don't have access to.

Comment: Are you trying to grab the output of openAL?

Comment: @AranMulholland That would be ideal, but I doubt it's possible :(

Comment: Hoping to bump this question, as this is a really annoying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can gain acces to the `AUGraph` then this is possible. According to the [AUGraph documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AUGraphServicesReference/AUGraphServicesReference.pdf) there is a couple of methods that would help you.

`AUGraphGetNodeCount` - to get the number of nodes in a graph
`AUGraphGetIndNode` - to get an indexed node
`AUGraphNodeInfo` - to get information about a node

Once you had the correct node you could get the remoteIO unit and add your callback. Gaining access to the `AUGraph` is actually the real issue.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks! This is probably going to be as close as anyone gets to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. If you do find a way to access the AUGraph I would love to hear about how you did it, it's a bit of a 'holy grail' as it would allow access to openAL to save the output or add effects which would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one RemoteIO. I have never tried to get a pointer to it while not being the one to "create" it. why don't you try something like this, it should get you a pointer to the RemoteIO:

```
OSStatus status;
AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

    // Describe audio component
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

// Get component
AudioComponent outputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

// Get audio units
status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(outputComponent, &audioUnit);
checkStatus(status);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure that doing what you suggest will instantiate a *new* instance of a RemoteIO audio unit.

Comment: hmmm yea tested it after one had already been created. I was hoping doing that again would just return a pointer to the fist one created. The funny thing is the result code returns 0 but the outInstance is not pointing to anything. so I guess it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there can be multiple AUGraphs running in the same app.

Comment: Can there be multiple AURemoteIO?